# Execute a recording from code on Ranorex

Tags: ranorex

Does anyone know how to execute a recording file (rxrec) from code (I am using C#)?
I did look for examples and I couldn't find any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standalone recorder (not in Ranorex Studio!!), you can export the recording to as an executable. You can call the EXE file in your code.

[image]

Comment: Thats great! but how do I join the reports into the main report? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Ranorex API for this. Just use this line of code.

```
NameOfYourRecording.Run();
```

Comment: I can do that only if I use the Ranorex IDE and I import the rxrec file into the IDE and it creates "cs" files from the "rxrec" file that contains this method.
My question is how do I run an "rxrec" file on runtime, not something I can load into the IDE.

Comment: That's not possible at all

Comment: p.s. I dug through the code and I understood that what the Ranorex studio is doing is using the rxrec file (which is an XML) to generate the rxrec.cs file using Microsoft code generator.
The recorder is doing the same.
Ranorex can just export this code that generates the "cs" file and all of the problems would be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried yet, but you can execute a testcase through command line:
[run outside ranorex IDE](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-4-ranorex-test-suite.html#c4827)

So if you execute something similar in your C#, I guess it should do the trick. It's not really executing an rxrec file from your code, but result should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to execute the Ranorex recording from a different C# project.
You can compile your Ranorex project as ".dll" and then add reference to this dll in your other project.
After this you should be able to run any recording with {RecordingName}.Start().